# add/delete a cytoscape style

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

here it is stated that we can add a style. https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.style I want to add and/or remove that style dynamically on js.

An alternative might be updating the style as empty.

#### a workaround

Add the style to cytoscape.js but give it a unique *selector*.

`cy.style().selector('edge.nolabel')
      .style({ 'label': '' })
      .update();`

Here I added a new style but is for only edges with ***nolabel*** class. Later you can add/remove classes from your edges to see the effect of applying this style.

ps: Rather than a question, this might have been a feature request

Comment: It seems like you have all you need in that documentation. If not, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I want to remove the particular style if it exists. It does not mentioned in the doc

Comment: This is a very specific question about cytoscape.js. I know how to add remove properties from a javascript object. I'm depending totally on cytoscape.js API

Comment: As a workaround, I'm adding styles at the beginning to cytoscape style. Then I add/remove the class from my cytoscape elements

Comment: Can you add an example for this case? With a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your question will be much easier to answer. Thanks <3